# Delphi how to do SearchReplace in a component property in all the files of a project?

Tags: delphi, replace, dfm

I need to do a SearchReplace in all my forms (all the dfm) for changing all the occurences of ':' to ';' in all the `TQuery.Strings` (of type `TStrings`).

How can I accomplish this? I'd like to do it at desing time: I would like that my dfm contain ";", not do a runtime substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Try e.g. CnPack, what is huge set of useful addons. In this pack it's called Property Corrector.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're storing all your .dfm files in text format, just use any of the simple grep tools available.

If you're not sure if you're storing your .dfm files in text, right click on a form and see if the checkbox below set.

[image]

As I recall, there are other good reasons to store .dfm's as text. And, there's a command line tool to convert all .dfm's in a directory tree to text. See this thread: [link text](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=28987)

Comment: I support the idea of using regular expressions to search and replace stuff in DFMs, but you need some mighty powerful regex engine to handle this case: First of all it needs to do multi-line matches, I haven't found something free that does it on windows. Next you need to use some crazy amounts of lookahead and lookbehind, because you want to match just the ";" but in some pretty restrictive places. Can you suggest a tool?

Comment: Also check the CnPack's Property Corrector. It supports simple regular expressions, property changing rules and it's easy to use.

Comment: I feel the only way to do it is making a tool that parses all dfm and as it finds TQuery, it searches for SQL than it reads all the text up to the next "end" and does a ReplaceStr. Of course this is not a Wizard, it is computer "assisted manual replacement".

Comment: @user193655, when it comes to one-time-jobs like that, the fastest hack that can be deployed is the best! A delphi app that parses enough of the DFM to make that very simple change can't take longer then 30 minutes; Looking for better options will surely take longer.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund, yes I agree and it's what I attempted.